# Android catch onclick event from a button created programmatically

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have created a button programmatically in a Layout, but now I can not find the way to catch your onClick event.
The code is as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

int wrapContent = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpView = new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button");
            linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);

}//fin de onCreate


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn:  //Here the problem begins with error 'btn'

            break;


    }

   }
}
```

How can I make it recognize the symbol 'btn' object that was created programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I can't find a question that's already been written about this...

If you [read the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button), Google tells you what to do right at the top of the page: `button.setOnClickListener()`. In your case:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: But how can he find the id?

Comment: It doesn't have an ID, because you didn't give it one.

Answer (score 0):

Like @TheWanderer said you haven't specified an ID

```
btn.setId(your_set_id);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then later

```
switch(item.getItemId()) { 

case R.id.your_set_id:
break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set ID for dynamically created button like this:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Button");
btn.setId(4); //give a positive integer
```

then get the ID of button like this:

```
int buttonID = btn.getId();
```

and

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonID :  
            //do something
            break;
    }
   }
}
```

**Edited:**

```
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this) //add this line.
    btn.setText("Button");
    btn.setId(4); //give a positive integer
    linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);
```

Comment: Applying this solution, the system generates the following error in the line:
'case R.id.buttonID -> Cannot resolve simbol "buttonID" '
in OnClick.

Comment: I forget add event listener

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I achieved the goal, however I would have liked the solution to be using SWITCH CASE for several buttons, being able to identify them by their ID.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
int wrapContent = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent);



            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button");
            linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"click btn." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                         }
                                     }
    );

}//end de onCreate
}
```